# ORACLE PL/SQL Variable Function Scope - Need Explanation

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, stored-functions

I just tripped over an answer to a problem I was having with a PL/SQL variable not being recognized by a function and I was hoping someone could explain to me why my solution worked and what is happening "underneath the hood".

**Background**

As part of an optimization project, I am trying to collect metrics on individual SQL scripts within a Stored Procedure. The Stored Proc that I am dissecting has an In-type date parameter that I need to define in order to run each individual SQL Script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE myStoredProc (DATE_IN DATE, ERROR_OUT OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    --Truncate Temp Tables
    --6 Individual SQL Scripts
EXCEPTION
    --Error Handling
END;
```

To run each script individually, I decided to just drop each SQL statement into a PL/SQL block and feed the `DATE_IN` parameter in as a variable:

```
DECLARE
    DATE_IN DATE := TO_DATE('16-JUL-2014','DD-MON-RR'); 
BEGIN
    --Place individual script here
END;
```

**The Problem**

This approach worked fine for a couple of the queries that referred to this `DATE_IN` variable but one query with a reference to an outside function which  takes `DATE_IN` as a parameter started throwing an ORA-00904 error:

```
DECLARE  
    DATE_IN DATE := TO_DATE('16-JUL-2014','DD-MON-RR'); 
BEGIN
    insert into temp_table
    SELECT table1.field1,
           table1.field2,
           table2.fieldA,
           MyFunction(table1.field1, DATE_IN) --This was the problem line
      FROM
           table1,
           table2
     WHERE EXISTS (inner query)
       AND table1.keys = table2.keys
       AND table2.date <= DATE_IN
END;
```

**Solution**

At the advice of another Developer, I was able to get around this error by adding a colon (:) in front of the `DATE_IN` variable that I was passing into the function so that the problem line read `MyFunction(table1.field1, :DATE_IN)`. As soon as I did that, my error disappeared and I was able to run the query without issue.

I was happy for the result but the other Developer wasn't able to explain why it was needed, only that it was necessary to call any functions or other stored procs from a PL/SQL statement. I assume this has something to do with scope but I would like to get a better explanation as to why this colon was necessary for the function to see the variable.

**Questions**

I've tried to do a little research looking over Oracle documentation on parameters, [variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12050.htm), [binding/declaring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci05bnd.htm) and [constants](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/constant.htm#LNPLS01310) but my research has only given me more questions:

- After reading up on variables, I now question if that is the correct term for what I have been using (since I didn't actually use the VARIABLE command and I'm passing in a date - which is not an allowable data type). If my `DATE_IN DATE :=` statement is not a variable, then what is it?
- Why were the rest of my references to `DATE_IN` recognized by the compiler but passing the value to the function was out of scope?
- What exactly is the colon (:) doing here? Is this turning that into a bind variable?

Thanks in advance. I appreciate any guidance you can provide!

**----------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------**

I was asked to provide additional information. My Db version is 11G, 11.2.0.2.0. The query that I was able to reproduce this error is below.

```
DECLARE  
    EXTRACT_DT_IN DATE := TO_DATE('16-JUL-2014','DD-MON-RR'); 
BEGIN
    --This begins the pre-optimized query that I'm testing
    insert into AELI_COV_TMP_2_OPT
    SELECT /*+ ordered use_nl(CM MAMT) INDEX (CM CSMB_CSMB2_UK) INDEX (MAMT     (MBAM_CSMB_FK_I) */
           CM.CASE_MBR_KEY
          ,CM.pyrl_no
          ,MAMT.AMT
          ,MAMT.FREQ_CD
          ,MAMT.HOURS
          ,aeli$cov_pdtodt(CM.CASE_MBR_KEY, EXTRACT_DT_IN)
      FROM
           CASE_MEMBERS CM
          ,MEMBER_AMOUNTS MAMT
      WHERE EXISTS (select /*+ INDEX(SDEF SLRY_BCAT_FK_I) */
                      'x'
                     from SALARY_DEF SDEF
                    where SDEF.CASE_KEY = CM.CASE_KEY
                      AND SDEF.TYP_CD = '04'
                      AND SDEF.SLRY_KEY = MAMT.SLRY_KEY)
       AND CM.CASE_MBR_KEY = MAMT.CASE_MBR_KEY
       AND MAMT.STAT_CD = '00'
       AND (MAMT.xpir_dt is null or MAMT.xpir_dt > EXTRACT_DT_IN)
       AND MAMT.eff_dt <= EXTRACT_DT_IN;
    --This ends the pre-optimized query that I'm testing
END;
```

Here is the error I'm encountering when trying to run an Explain Plan on this statement. I am able to get past this error if I remove reference to line 13 or I add a colon (:) to the `EXTRACT_DT_IN` on that line.

[image: Error Encountered on Explain Plan]

**----------------------EDIT 2-------------------**

Here is the function signature of aeli$.cov_pdtodt. (I've replaced the owner for security reasons).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function __owner__.aeli$cov_pdtodt
(CASE_MBR_KEY_IN IN NUMBER, EXTRACT_EFF_DT_IN DATE)
  RETURN DATE IS
    PDTODT  DATE;
```

Comment: Assuming you insert has a semicolon at the end, what you have should work. Making a reference to `:date_in` should error (or prompt) if you haven't declared it already, e.g. with `variable`. Seems to work fine in 11gR2; what version are you using, and which client (and version)? Not sure why you think it's a scope issue as you don't have sub-blocks or repeated names.

Comment: I'm afraid the minimal example in OP doesn't demonstrate the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can't recreate this behaviour in 10.2.0.5 (SQL*Plus), [11.2.0.2 (SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/711af0/1), or 11.2.0.3 (SQL Developer). What you're saying doesn't really make sense, and unless you can create a reproducible example it's not really clear what we'd be trying to explain

Comment: Thank you both for replying - I'll post the actual query I was getting the error to see if that better shows the error. Though without the Stored Proc or Function I don't know that you will be able to recreate the issue.

Comment: @DanK - I don't see that your real query is significantly different from the demo one, or the Fiddle that worked. I don't think it's relevant but what is the signature of the function you're calling?

Comment: An explain plain of just that SQL insert statement would get ORA-00904; you can't run an explain plan of the whole anonymous block. You're question suggests you're getting the error executing the anonymous block, is that not the case - you only get it running the insert (or select) part stand-alone, either as a command or explaining the plan?

Comment: It looks like the error is coming from trying to run an explain plan on the query (and not from trying to execute the entire anonymous block).  Since the explain plan is just for the insert statement, it doesn't have access to the variable declaration, which is why you get the error.  When you put the colon in front of the variable name, you are turning it into a bind variable, which is why it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your anonymous block is fine as it is, as long as you execute the whole block. If you try to execute just the `insert`, or its `select`, as a standalone command then it will indeed fail with ORA-00904.

That isn't quite a *scope* problem, it's a *context* problem. You're trying to refer to a PL/SQL variable in an SQL context, and that is never going to work.

In a PL/SQL context this would work:

```
declare
  some_var dual.dummy%type := 'X';
begin
  insert into some_table
  select dummy from dual where dummy = some_var;
end;
/
```

... because the insert has access to the PL/SQL `some_var`.

In an SQL context this will error:

```
select * from dual where dummy = some_var;
```

... because it's looking for a column called `SOME_VAR`, and there isn't one.

If you do this instead:

```
select * from dual where dummy = :some_var;
```

... the `some_var` is now a client-managed bind variable. If you execute that you'll either be prompted for the bind value, or given a not-all-variables-bound error, or bind-variable-not-declared, or similar, depending on your client.

If you only do an explain plan of that though, e.g. with

```
set auto trace traceonly explain
select * from dual where dummy = :some_var;
```

... then the bind variable doesn't necessarily have to be populated for the plan to be calculated. Some clients may still complain and want a bind value, but the parser would be OK with it - enough to produce a plan anyway. Though not able to take advantage of bind variable peeking or histograms etc.

For example, SQL Developer happily produces a plan for your original sample query if both references are turned into bind variables, just the `insert ...` part of the block is selected, and you press Explain Plan (F10).

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, Alex. I'm using TOAD and based on your comments, I think I need to research more how Explain Plan is working with these PL/SQL Blocks. As you mention, when I run the SQL Statement above by itself, I get that ORA-00904 error. However, when I wrap it in the PL/SQL declaration and define the variable, I am able to run Explain Plan on just the SQL statement. But when I run it around the entire block it gives me a ORA-00905 error.

Comment: Just talked to another developer and it sounds like the same situation that Alex describes above happens when I wrap my SQL in a PL/SQL Block. Even though I only run the explain plan on the single SQL statement, the engine knows to go out and see that a variable exists somewhere and it "fills in a blank" so that it can run Explain Plan. Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you read, but you're mixed up on a few things here.

Your DATE_IN is a variable. You don't need to type 'VARIABLE' anywhere to declare a variable, all you need is the name of the variable and the datatype. 
All of the below are legitimate variables in PL/SQL (although poorly named).

```
variable_1 NUMBER;
variable_2 VARCHAR2(100);
variable_3 DATE;
```

It's hard to tell what you're doing in your code without seeing it all. Do you have two DATE_IN variables declared within the same block? Is DATE_IN the name of a column in your table?

If you have a column named DATE_IN in table1 or table2, that's likely your problem. Oracle doesn't know if you want to use your variable or your column, and it will always default to the column name. Your function would be expecting a DATE and receiving a column, hence the error.

Comment: This is where I'm getting mixed up on Variables. They seem to take on different behavior when using that VAR or VARIABLE command: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12050.htm

Comment: @DanK - `variable` is an SQL*Plus (or SQL Developer) command that creates a bind variable, not an SQL or PL/SQL command. Totally unrelated to a PL/SQL `declare` section or PL/SQL variables.

Comment: Ah.. that makes a lot more sense now. I've seen references to bind variables in the past but the explanation never made sense before. As a SQL Plus command, however, I see how they work. Thanks!